# Access backref on relationship when filtering in SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlalchemy

I have a table named `ExtendedUser` that has a one to one relationship with a `User` table with a backref named `extended_user` on the `User` table. The `User` table has a one to many relationship with the `UserPosts` table with a backref named `posts` on the `User` table.

```py
class User(Base):
    __tablename__ = "users"

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)

class UserPost(Base):
    __tablename__ = "user_posts"

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    user_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey("users.id"))
    user = relationship("User", backref="posts")

class ExtendedUser(Base):
    __tablename__ = "extended_users"

    user_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey("users.id"), primary_key=True)
    user = relationship("User", backref="extended_user", uselist=False, lazy="joined")
```

Starting from `ExtendedUser`, I want to select all the `ExtendedUser`s whose `User`s has no post.
So what I've unsuccessfully tried to do is

```py
sess.query(ExtendedUser).filter(not_(ExtendedUser.user.posts.any()))
```

But that does not work, I get an error:

```
AttributeError: Neither 'InstrumentedAttribute' object nor 'Comparator' object associated with ExtendedUser.user has an attribute 'posts'
```

How can I model my query so that only `ExtendedUser`s whose `User` has `UserPost`s be returned?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error occurs because the `.user` attribute is a different thing depending on whether you access it from the class, or an instance of the class. For example, this raises the exception that you are getting:

```py
ExtendedUser.user.posts
```

This is because accessing `.user` on the class `ExtendedUser` returns an `InstrumentedAttribute` object, and instances of `InstrumentedAttribute` have no attribute called `posts`.

This works:

```py
inst = ExtendedUser()
inst.user.posts
```

The above works because we've accessed `.user` on an *instance* of `ExtendedUser`, which returns an *instance* of `User` that has an attribute called `posts`.

This differing behavior between class and instance attribute access is controlled by Python's [descriptor protocol](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/descriptor.html).

One way to achieve your objective would be to use a subquery to query for unique `user_id`s in the `user_posts` table, and test that the `ExtendedUser`'s `user_id` isn't in the result:

```
q = sess.query(ExtendedUser).\
    filter(
        not_(
            ExtendedUser.user_id.in_(
                sess.query(UserPost.user_id).distinct()
            )
        )
    )
```

The following is a working example, but first I had to change the definition of `ExtendedUser.user` a little:

```py
class ExtendedUser(Base):
    ...
    user = relationship(
        "User", backref=backref("extended_user", uselist=False), lazy="joined")
```

Note the use of the `backref` function which allows me to set `uselist=False` on `User.extended_user`. Your example has `uselist=False` on `ExtendedUser.user` but it isn't needed there as the Foreign Key is defined on `ExtendedUser`, so `ExtendedUser.user` can only ever point to one user, and sqlalchemy will automatically know that the collection shouldn't be a list. Without that change I'd get a `TypeError: Incompatible collection type: ExtendedUser is not list-like` exception.

OK here's the example:

```
sess = Session()
user_1 = User(extended_user=ExtendedUser())
user_2 = User(extended_user=ExtendedUser())
user_3 = User(extended_user=ExtendedUser())
user_1.posts = [UserPost()]
sess.add_all([user_1, user_2, user_3])
sess.commit()
q = sess.query(ExtendedUser).\
    filter(
        not_(
            ExtendedUser.user_id.in_(
                sess.query(UserPost.user_id).distinct()
            )
        )
    )

print(q.all())  # [ExtendedUser(user_id=2), ExtendedUser(user_id=3)]
```

Comment: Thanks, this is a good solution. The approach I used comes from my Entity Framework background where an expression like that works seamlessly. I realize now that SQLAlchemy is perhaps closer to pure SQL (lower level), which means there's less magic, but the generated queries are probably much simpler.

Comment: I can't upvote you because of my low rep, I would if I could. Sorry.

Comment: No worries, happy to help. There may well be other solutions, this is just one I felt was straight forward. All the best.